# Creating views through hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, view, annotations

Is there any way to create a view when creating tables by using the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property. I am using annotation type for defining the table and its fields. Is there any property that I can use to create the view also through hibernate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate does not do that for you automatically. However, one of these solutions might be useful to you:

1. Create a view in your database, and define a model with those columns using hibernate. Hibernate does not create a table for that model, if it finds this view. And the rest is just like using a real table.
2. Hibernate does give you the ability to create (and drop) additional database objects yourself in the XML mapping files. Something like this.

   ```
   <database-object>
      <create>create or replace view yourView</create>
      <drop>drop view yourView</drop>
      <dialect-scope name='org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect' />
   </database-object>
   ```

In my opinion the first solutions is way easier to handle, as I am currently using this method to treat my views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..so we should create the view manually after we create all the tables through hibernate. we have to run view creation query once the table creation is successful..am i right..?

Comment: Yes, and if `hibernate` has created a table for your view, don't forget to drop it. Creating a script for such views are highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..tried to create view through hibernate. but i couldn't do it..so your idea is the best one.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to put the view creation sql in a script that is run by hbm2ddl by configuring property

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files
```

Assuming that you have an entity that represents that view, you must do a drop table before creating the view, since hbm2ddl will create a table if it doesn't find an existing view by that name.