# How to do a division, calculate a percentage in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to calculate a percentage but the compiler keeps telling me it doesn't expect the slash and the third select statement.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Reservation r WHERE r.begin BETWEEN :start AND :end) 
/
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Reservation res WHERE res.begin BETWEEN :start AND :end AND res.contract IS NOT NULL) * 100");
```

When I try to run this, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i googled java hibernate formula division  see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

Comment: So did I, maybe I missed it but I can't seem to find what's wrong. If you do, please care to explain.

Comment: try and create a view from two selects and then use the view and see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215757/creating-views-through-hibernate , unfortunately this is all i can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both counts can be combined to one query:

```
SELECT (count(r.contract) / count(r)) * 100 
FROM Reservation r 
WHERE r.begin between :start and :end
```

In some databases that leads to integer division and following is then better:

```
SELECT (count(r.contract)*1.0 / count(r)) * 100 
FROM Reservation r 
WHERE r.begin between :start and :end
```